# Latex Expression in Legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I want to add a latex expression in my legend like red-colored. I tried the following code, but I could not do that. How do I manage this issue? Also, I got a waring about this code. How do I remove that?

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(C, aes(sigma, value)) +
    geom_line(aes(linetype=name)) +
    scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "twodash", "dotted")) +
    scale_linetype_discrete(labels = c(expression("X_A = 1 \\& X_B =0"),
                                       expression("X_A = 3 \\& X_B =0"),
                                       expression("X_A = 5 \\& X_B =0"))) +
    theme_minimal() +
    xlab("standard diviation") +
    ylab("rejection rate") +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(legend.position = c(0.15, 0.85),
          legend.background = element_rect(fill="white", 
                                           size=0.5,
                                           linetype="solid",
                                           colour ="gray"),
          legend.spacing.y = unit(0, "pt"),
          text = element_text(size=20),
          legend.text = element_text(size=20),
          axis.title=element_text(size=20),
          legend.title = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major.y = element_line(),
          panel.grid.minor.y = element_line())
```

```
Scale for 'linetype' is already present. Adding another scale for 'linetype',
which will replace the existing scale.
```

Comment: Can't replicate and test without any example, but see package ``latex2exp`` and try if that helps.

Comment: Example code: ``require(latex2exp);
require(ggplot2);
p <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat, y=price, color=cut)) + ggtitle(TeX(r'($\rho = 1, \sigma = 2, \epsilon = 2$)'))``

Comment: Here the ``ggtitle`` is formed in latex style. RStudio might not show them correctly in the preview, but when printed to PDF they're always there